# Adding a <script> tag in URL causes 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: asp.net, url, http-status-code-404, iis-6, http-status-code-400

Adding a  tag in URL causes 400 Bad Request Error. I have redirected users to generic error pages created by me for any error occurring on my site. 
I am using `<customerrors>` tags in web.config to redirect users for any error occurring on the site.

For eg.

`http://www.example.com/ABC/<script>alert('Hi');<script>.aspx` -- Redirects to 400 Bad Request Page

`http://www.example.com/ABC/frmLogin.aspx?<script>alert('Hi');<script>` -- Redirects to Custom Error Page as defined in web.config

I have deployed my site on IIS 5 and also on IIS 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you closely look into url `http://www.example.com/ABC/<script>alert('Hi');<script>.aspx`, this means you are requesting a page `"something.aspx"`, that is why it says 400 bad request, it is not  `internal server error - http status 500`. And that is why it not redirecting to custom error page, as they are meant for `http status 500 - server error`. To solve this, you need to handle 400 status , and redirect to required page.